# None of my Antigen bundles are loading

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

https://github.com/ehellman/dotfiles

These are the dotfiles I am using at the moment that are relevant. `antigen.zsh` is in the same folder.

I have followed the tutorial from the github repo on how to get going, it creates the `~/.antigen/` directory containing a `/repos/` folder. So it has cloned down the things I want, but using the commands in my `.zshrc` has no effect at all and I can't find a good way to debug this.

Yes, the command `antigen` works, running `antigen bundle <package>` works too, it clones but it won't enable the package afterwards.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

in my case I didn't finished antigen commands with `antigen apply`

this is how looks my .zshrc:

```
source /usr/local/share/antigen/antigen.zsh
antigen bundle Tarrasch/zsh-colors
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
antigen apply
```

after adding `antigen apply` in the end - now bundles loaded and work when I open new console window